# How to generate random numbers in multiple processes at the same time?

Tags: c, random

How can I generate random numbers in C for multiple processes being run at exactly the same time?

I wanted to use `srand` and `rand` but I don't know how (maybe using the process ID?).

Comment: `rand` and `srand` do not "work with seconds". They don't even look at the clock.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6161322/using-rand-with-multiple-threads-in-c

Comment: Maybe you are confused because the `srand` function is often called with the the result of the `time` function as argument?

Comment: Maybe use the process ID in `srand` seed like `srand(time(NULL) * processID)`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use a different seed for each process, based on the process id for example :

```
srand(getpid());
```

And then just use `rand()`.

Comment: Or why not combine time and pid for the seed: `srand(getpid() * time(NULL));`

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Yes, that can be a good idea too, but that's not an obligation so I took the easier way ;)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, what's the different seeding along with time(NULL) if concurrently executing?

Comment: @ReneWang The `rand` and `srand` functions are not reentrant, if you call `srand` with different values in different threads then each call will overwrite the stored seed from a previous call and you will have data-races. Also since `time` usually have only second resolution calling `time(NULL)` multiple times in a single second will give the same result, which can cause multiple processes to use the same seed and the same "random" sequence".

Answer (score 1):

After years and years of weird errors from poor random seeds, I eventually wrote a code to get random numbers from `/dev/urandom`, which are the same random numbers used for SSL.  In my code I used these "good" random numbers to seed the C stdlib rand() function, which was sufficent for my task as long as it got a good seed:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//HOW MANY BITS IN A CHAR? THIS MACRO IS USUALLY DEFINED
#ifndef CHAR_BIT
#define CHAR_BIT 8
#endif

//PATH TO RANDOM NUMBER GENERATOR
const char inPath[]="/dev/urandom";

//EXTRACTS A PSEUDORANDOM unsigned long FROM THE OPERATING SYSTEM VIA /dev/urandom
unsigned long get_urandom(){

  //OPEN INPUT STREAM
  FILE *inFile;
  inFile=fopen(inPath,"r");

  //FAILED TO OPEN STREAM
  if(inFile==NULL){
    fprintf(stderr, "# Failed to open random device %s\n", inPath);
    return 0;
  }

  //HOW MANY BITS IN A CHAR? HOW MANY CHARS IN AN UNSIGNED LONG?
  const int bitsInChar  = CHAR_BIT;
  const int charsInLong = sizeof(unsigned long) / sizeof(char);

  //GET RANDOM UNSIGNED LONG ONE CHARACTER AT A TIME
  unsigned long randomSeed=0;
  for(int i=0; i<charsInLong; i++)
    randomSeed |= fgetc(inFile) << i*bitsInChar;

  //CLOSE STREAM AND RETURN
  fclose(inFile);
  return randomSeed;

}

int main(){

  // We can use the above function directly to get our random numbers, but this is slow.
  printf("We can get random numbers from the OS via get_urandom: %u\n", get_urandom());  

  // Or we can just call get_urandom once, to use as a seed for the stdlib rand() function.
  unsigned int randomSeed=get_urandom();
  srand(randomSeed);
  printf("Or, using a random seed from get_urandom: %u\n", randomSeed);
  printf("We can get random numbers from stdlib, e.g.: %u\n", rand());
}
```

Here's the same code again with the function rewritten in C++:

```
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

//HOW MANY BITS IN A CHAR? THIS MACRO IS USUALLY DEFINED
#ifndef CHAR_BIT
#define CHAR_BIT 8
#endif

//EXTRACTS A PSEUDORANDOM unsigned long FROM THE OPERATING SYSTEM VIA /dev/urandom
unsigned long get_urandom(const char inPath[]="/dev/urandom"){

  //OPEN INPUT STREAM
  ifstream inFile(inPath);

  //FAILED TO OPEN STREAM
  if(inFile.fail()){
    fprintf(stderr, "# Failed to open random device %s\n", inPath);
    return 0;
  }

  //HOW MANY BITS IN A CHAR? HOW MANY CHARS IN AN UNSIGNED LONG?
  const int bitsInChar  = CHAR_BIT;
  const int charsInLong = sizeof(unsigned long) / sizeof(char);

  //GET RANDOM UNSIGNED LONG ONE CHARACTER AT A TIME
  unsigned long randomSeed=0;
  for(int i=0; i<charsInLong; i++)
    randomSeed |= inFile.get() << i*bitsInChar;

  //CLOSE STREAM AND RETURN
  inFile.close();
  return randomSeed;

}

int main(){

  // We can use the above function directly to get our random numbers, but this is slow.
  printf("We can get random numbers from the OS via get_urandom: %u\n", get_urandom());  

  // Or we can just call get_urandom once, to use as a seed for the stdlib rand() function.
  unsigned int randomSeed=get_urandom();
  srand(randomSeed);
  printf("Or, using a random seed from get_urandom: %u\n", randomSeed);
  printf("We can get random numbers from stdlib, e.g.: %u\n", rand());
}
```