# How to parallelize a function, that uses some variable

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have a function, that generates random URL, and try to download the file.

```
void tryURL()
{
    randURL.clear();
    for (unsigned short i = 0; i < urlLength; i++)  {
    randURL = randURL + (alphabet[(int)((double)rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1) * alphabetLength)]);
    }
    wcout << randURL << endl;
    HRESULT getImg = URLDownloadToFile(NULL, LPCWSTR( (beginURL + randURL + endURL).c_str() ), LPCWSTR( (randURL + L"/" + endURL).c_str() ), 0, NULL);
    if (SUCCEEDED(getImg))
    {
    wcout << L"Success" << endl;
    }
}
```

If I execute this function normally, It's work fine:

```
tryURL();
0ybOAt
tryURL();
lTPKaR
tryURL();
Ivi05m
...
```

But, I need to run this function repeatedly times at that moment.
I tried this:

```
thread threads[10];

for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    threads[i] = thread(tryURL);
}

for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    threads[i].join();
}
```

And it always returns me same value

```
0ybOAt0ybOAt
0ybOAt

0ybOAt0ybOAt

0ybOAt
0ybOAt0ybOAt
0ybOAt
0ybOAt
```

And even endl don't show's up sometimes.

How can I fix it? I think, it broken because always using same variable randURL, but I don't know how to evade this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the same variable, make `tryURL` **return** the URL:

```
// assuming that URLs are strings
std::string tryURL() { /* ... */ }
```

Then, create a vector of `std::future<std::string>` to represent the asynchronous computations that will return URLs:

```
std::vector<std::future<std::string>>> futures;
futures.reserve(10);

for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) 
{
    futures.emplace_back(std::async(std::launch::async, tryURL));
}
```

Finally, consume the URLs in the main thread:

```
for(auto& f : futures) 
{
    consume(f.get());
}
```

Comment: Can't get this code working on VC17. launch_async replaced with launch::async, but consume command not found.
Can you fix it?

Comment: @megapro17: `consume` is just an example. That's where your logic should go.

Answer (score 0):

Other questions on StackOverflow provide some clues:

- [rand() with multiple threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15411061/rand-with-multiple-threads)
- [iostream thread safety, must cout and cerr be locked separately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637595/iostream-thread-safety-must-cout-and-cerr-be-locked-separately)

A simple fix for the rand() issue is to generate the URL:s in the main thread and pass them to the thread.

```
void tryURL(std::wstring URL)
...
// TODO: Set randURL to a random URL
threads[i] = thread(tryURL, randURL);
```

Comment: ok, I fixed the rand. but my program runs only it 4 threads. I can't get why. I tried more, but only 4 threads at one time only executed. Also, I have 4 cores CPU. 
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
   thr[i] = thread(tryURL);
  }