# Openmp for in a loop, where to seed random number generator?

Tags: c, random, thread-safety, openmp

I've read that, in order to ensure thread safety, it's convenient to seed the `RNG` inside the parallel region like this:

```
int seedbase = 392872;

#pragma omp parallel 
{
   srand(omp_get_thread_id * seedbase);
   #pragma omp for
   ....
}
```

But what if my parallelized section is inside another loop?  If I had a situation like this:

```
int seedbase = 392872;
for(int i=0; i<100; ++i)
{
    #pragma omp parallel 
    {
      srand(omp_get_thread_id * seedbase);
      #pragma omp for
      ....
    }
}
```

Where should I initialize my `RNG`?

Comment: So you *want* each iteration to create a group of threads that join at the end of it?

Comment: Yes, because the outer loop range could be very small, so, let's say I have 8 threads, if I put my omp for before it,  and the loop range is (0,3), I don't get all threads working, while in this case, since my inner loop it's surely greater than 8, I am sure that I get all threads working

Comment: Related: [Using stdlib's rand() from multiple threads](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6161322/2402272).

Comment: Yes, I'm currently using rand_r so it's more thread safe. The problem remains, how do I correctly initialize it?

Comment: You don't use `srand()` with `rand_r()` *at all*, see `man rand_r`: *Like  rand(),  rand_r()  returns  a  pseudo-random  integer  in  the  range
       [0, RAND_MAX].   The seedp argument is a pointer to an unsigned int that is
       used to store state between calls.  If rand_r() is  called  with  the  same
       initial  value  for  the integer pointed to by seedp, and that value is not
       modified between calls, then the same pseudo-random sequence will result.*

Answer (score 2):

> I've read that, in order to ensure thread safety, it's convenient to seed the RNG inside the parallel region like this:

Convenience notwithstanding, your technique is not *effective*.  Regardless of where you call `srand()`, the standard `rand()` function cannot be made thread safe.  It relies on internal static data that is modified on every call, so if you call it (or `srand()`) from multiple threads without some kind of synchronization then you thereby create a data race.

At one time POSIX defined a function `rand_r()`.  If you have that then it would serve your purpose, but it has now been marked obsolete.  The correct use of `rand_r()` with OpenMP would involve establishing a private (OpenMP sense) variable inside the parallel region to hold the seed.  Initialize it differently or identically in each thread, depending on whether you want the same sequence of random numbers in each thread.  You then pass a pointer to that variable as the argument to `rand_r()`.  After each call, you probably want to take the return value, or something derived from it, as the new seed.

Comment: If rand_r is now obsolete, what (standard) function should I call?

Comment: It depends on what platform(s) you're programming for.  Although it is obsolete, there is no direct replacement for `rand_r()`, and it is unlikely that implementations will actually remove it in the foreseeable future.  You could consider using it anyway.  Alternatively, if you only need to support glibc-based systems, then there is also `random_r()` (and an accompanying `srandom_r()`.