# why I need to use rand_r() in threads and why I need different seed for each threads?

Tags: c, multithreading, thread-safety, pthreads, random-seed

I can't understand why I have to use `rand_r()` in generating random numbers in a thread function. And also why I need to use different seed for each thread.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using stdlib's rand() from multiple threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6161322/using-stdlibs-rand-from-multiple-threads)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why I need different seed in each?

`rand_r()` is a pseudo-random number generator. That is to say, it generates a pseduo-random *sequence* of numbers: Each call returns the next number in the sequence.

"Random" means "unpredictable." If you have a generator for a truly random sequence of numbers, you will be unable to predict the next number in the sequence, no matter how many of the preceding numbers you already know.

A "*Pseudo* random" is *like* a random sequence in some ways—can be used *as if* it was random in some applications—but it isn't random at all. In fact, it is 100% predictable. All you need to know to predict the next number in the sequence is to know the state of the generator and the algorithm that it uses.

The *seed* for a pseudo-random generator provides a way to put the generator into a known, repeatable state. If you provide the same seed to two different instances of the generator, then both generators will return exactly the same sequence of values.

---

Do you *want* each thread to get exactly the same sequence as every other thread? It's up to you. If that's what you want, then seed each one with the same value. If you want them to get different "random" numbers, then seed each generator with a different value.

Also, if you want different *runs* of the program to get different "random" values, then you have to seed with a different value each time the program is run.

Comment: P.S., If you're looking for a way to get different seed values each time you run the program, and if your program is intended to run under Linux, then you might want to read about the [`getrandom()` system call](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrandom.2.html).

Answer (score 0):

> why I need to use rand_r() in threads

From the documentation of `rand` : *The function rand() is not reentrant or thread-safe, ... this can be done using the reentrant function rand_r().*

> why I need different seed for each threads?

you don't necessary need, it is your choice to use or not the same seed in all the threads