# Poor CPU usage in a parallel loop

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp, cpu

[image]In the code below, I have a **parallel section** where each thread uses a private `vector<int>` to push and pop integers. The problem I have is that as I increase the number of threads, the **performance** of each core decreases drastically, and the **Kernel CPU** usage (red bar in the htop command) assigned to each core increases a lot. For example,  with 1 core I have 100% normal CPU usage, but with 25 cores (see image) almost all the CPU usage goes to the kernel.

It is probably something very basic, but I just don't know why it happens.  I would expect that since each thread has its own private variable each core would work exactly the same no matter the number of total CPUS used in the parallel section.

Any advise?

```
int cpus = 25;
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic,1)
for (int ss = 0; ss < cpus; ss++)
{
    std::vector<int> q;
    while (true)
    {
        q.push_back(rand());
        q.pop_back();
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6161322/using-stdlibs-rand-from-multiple-threads

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/rand: "It is implementation-defined whether rand() is thread-safe." - using stuff from `<random>` is probably better.

Comment: Thank you all!!!! yes, I just tried removing the random and it is working.

Comment: `rand` can either be not thread-safe, which makes your program undefined, or thread-safe, which makes your program non-parallel. (I suspect that the program spends all that kernel time waiting for it.)

Comment: The GLIBC implementation of `rand()` is not thread-safe.

Comment: Are you sure your while (1) does anything? I can imagine a clever compiler just optimize away a push_back followed by a pop_back.

Comment: I know it execute those lines @akirahinoshiro because the rand issues.

Comment: how can I close the question selecting a comment as the answer?? do I have to answer it myself?