# Unexpected number output

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

I'm trying to create a program that solves the problem of dining philosophers using posix threads. However, I got stuck at the very beginning, since the output of std :: cout << id + 1 << "PHILOSOPHER: thinking" << std :: endl; ++ i; is incorrect and id takes too large values. Please point out my mistake.

```
pthread_mutex_t mutexSpoon[PHILOSOPHERS];

pthread_t createThread(int number){
    pthread_t id;
    int rc = pthread_create(&id, NULL, philFunc, &number);
    if(rc){
        abort();
    }
    return id;
}

void *philFunc(void *arg){
    srand(time(0));
    int id = *(int*)arg;
    int leftSpoon = (id>0) ? id-1 : PHILOSOPHERS;
    int rightSpoon = id;
    int temp;
    int i = 0;
    while(i < 10){
        usleep((200 - 50) * ( (double)rand() / RAND_MAX ) + 50);
        std::cout << id+1 << " PHILOSOPHER: thinking" << std::endl; ++i;

    }
    return nullptr;
}
```

main.cpp

```
using namespace std;
extern pthread_mutex_t mutexSpoon[PHILOSOPHERS];

int main(){
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");


    for(int i = 0; i < PHILOSOPHERS; ++i)
        pthread_mutex_init(&mutexSpoon[i], NULL);


    vector<pthread_t> vecID(PHILOSOPHERS);

    for(int i = 0; i < PHILOSOPHERS; ++i)
        vecID[i] = createThread(i);

    for(int i = 0; i < PHILOSOPHERS; ++i)
        pthread_join(vecID[i], NULL);


    for(int i = 0; i < PHILOSOPHERS; ++i)
        pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutexSpoon[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In `pthread_create(&id, NULL, philFunc, &number);` you are passing the address of a local variable. Most likely the thread reads the variable only after `createThread` returned, then `&number` becomes a dangling pointer.

Comment: You most likely do not want `srand(time(0));` in your thread function. You should generally call it once at the beginning of your program in `main`.

Comment: You might want to prefer [C++ thread support library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread) over p-threads to be more portable.

Comment: Note that `rand` might not be thread safe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6161322/using-stdlibs-rand-from-multiple-threads

Comment: you likely missed lines where you're using `mutexSpoon`, prehistoricpenguin wanted to point it out

Comment: Yes, I know I have not written lines of code where I am using `mutexSpoon`, however the problem was not caused by the code that is using `mutexSpoon`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thread function uses an address for argument, which you pass as an address to a local variable of function `createThread` - `number`. The life span of argument should be not shorter than thread, so exactly same as the mutex. Using your snippets as base, I created an example which works around the issue:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void *philFunc(void *arg);

#define PHILOSOPHERS 10

struct Philosopher {
    pthread_mutex_t mutexSpoon;
    pthread_t id;
    int no;
};

Philosopher philosophers[PHILOSOPHERS]  = {};

pthread_t createThread(int& number){
    pthread_t id;
    int rc = pthread_create(&id, NULL, philFunc, &number);
    if(rc){
        abort();
    }
    return id;
}

void *philFunc(void *arg){
    srand(time(0));
    int id = *(int*)arg;
    int leftSpoon = (id>0) ? id-1 : PHILOSOPHERS;
    int rightSpoon = id;
    int temp;
    int i = 0;
    while(i < 10){
        usleep((200 - 50) * ( (double)rand() / RAND_MAX ) + 50);
        std::cout << id+1 << " PHILOSOPHER: thinking" << std::endl; ++i;

    }
    return nullptr;
}

extern pthread_mutex_t mutexSpoon[PHILOSOPHERS];

int main(){
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");

    for(int i = 0; i < PHILOSOPHERS; ++i) {
        pthread_mutex_init(&philosophers[i].mutexSpoon, NULL);
        philosophers[i].no = i;
        philosophers[i].id = createThread(philosophers[i].no);
    }
    
    for(int i = 0; i < PHILOSOPHERS; ++i)
        pthread_join(philosophers[i].id, NULL);


    for(int i = 0; i < PHILOSOPHERS; ++i)
        pthread_mutex_destroy(&philosophers[i].mutexSpoon);
    return 0;
}
```

As you see, there is now own structure `Philosopher` for each thread, storing its data as it should be. While `philosophers` here is an array, it can be any other container as long as its elements live long enough and aren't changing their addresses (requirement for some implementations of the pthread mutex).

Note that `createThread(int& number)` now takes its argument by reference, so the expression `&number` would get address of the actual object's location, not of local variable.

This code can be simpler, if using C++ thread support and `std::future`.

Comment: Thank you for help! Now everything works as it should.

Comment: Watch out. The placement of `srand` can cause bugs at least two different ways.

Comment: What's the usage of `mutexSpoon` here? Seems it's not necessary.

Comment: `std::cout << id+1 << " PHILOSOPHER: thinking" << std::endl;` this line can not enssure the two part will be printed in one line, we may get lines in mess.

Comment: @prehistoricpenguin yeah, it relies on implementation of console output.. and if replacing `cout` to any other stream, it would either get messed up or cause UB (e.g. some stringstream implementations). I just didn't change anything else in code that wasn't related to problem above. As regarding the mutex, it's likely something that OP didn't show us, maybe it was output syncing.  I left it in as a data somehow related to thread. The code is incomplete, some variable weren't used at all