Linux pthreads are extremely slow on multicore server
The server under consideration is equipped with two CPUs, each having 24 physical cores, and operates on Ubuntu 23.10. I observed a significant slowdown in one of my Python scripts, with its speed reduced to a hundredth when utilizing threads. Given the sometimes problematic nature of threading in Python, I wrote a simple test code in C to investigate this issue further. This code does not share any memory and so forth in its compute intensive parts.
Here is the relevant information:
$ cat /proc/version
Linux version 6.5.0-28-generic (buildd@lcy02-amd64-001) (x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-13 (Ubuntu 13.2.0-4ubuntu3) 13.2.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.41) #29-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu Mar 28 23:46:48 UTC 2024

The CPU is:
# cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "model name" | head -1
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 5118 CPU @ 2.30GHz

The test C code:
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int _memsize;
int _N;

double time_usec(void) {
    struct timeval tv;
    if (gettimeofday(&tv, NULL) == 0) {
        // Convert seconds to double and add microseconds divided by 1,000,000
        return tv.tv_sec + tv.tv_usec / 1000000.0;
    } else {
        // gettimeofday failed, handle error as appropriate
        perror("gettimeofday failed");
        return 0.0;
    }
}

void *test(void *arg)
{
    int M = 10000;
    double t0, t1;
    int count;
    int tot;
    unsigned char *mem;
    long int id = (long int)arg;
    int N = _N;
    int memsize = _memsize;

    printf("Threads=%d   memsize=%d\n", N, memsize);
    mem = (unsigned char *)malloc(memsize);

    for (int i=0; i < memsize; i++)
        mem[i] = random();

    t0 = time_usec();
    count = 0;
    tot = 0;
    while (1) {
        for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
            tot += mem[(rand()) % memsize];
            if (tot > 10000000) tot -= 10000000;
            count++;
        }
        t1 = time_usec();
        if ((t1 - t0) > 2.0) {
            double nop_per_sec = (double)count / (t1 - t0);
            t0 = t1;
            printf("%3ld  %15.2lf nop/sec\n", id, nop_per_sec / 1000000.0);
            count = 0;
            M = nop_per_sec*0.1;
        }
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(int argn, char *arg[]) {
    pthread_t thread;
    int rc;
    long t;

    _N = atoi(arg[1]);
    _memsize = atoi(arg[2]);

    for (t = 0; t < _N; t++) {
        printf("Creating thread %ld\n", t);
        rc = pthread_create(&thread, NULL, test, (void *)t);
        if (rc) {
            printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", rc);
            exit(-1);
        }
    }

    while (1) sleep(1);

    return 0;
}

The performance when using single thread:
$ ./perf 1 1000
Creating thread 0
Threads=1   memsize=1000
  0            60.61 nop/sec
  0            60.97 nop/sec
  0            61.05 nop/sec
  0            61.05 nop/sec

Which show 60M operations per second (an arbitrary but consistent unit). When I use 2 threads:
$ ./perf 2 1000
Creating thread 0
Creating thread 1
Threads=2   memsize=1000
Threads=2   memsize=1000
  0             0.79 nop/sec
  1             0.71 nop/sec
  0             0.80 nop/sec
  1             0.72 nop/sec
  0             0.79 nop/sec
  1             0.67 nop/sec

That show about 1/100 slowdown. CPU load is about 200% as expected. When I run two processes each having a single thread I do not observe such slowdown:
$ ./perf 1 1000 & ./perf 1 1000
[1] 4989
Creating thread 0
Threads=1   memsize=1000
Creating thread 0
Threads=1   memsize=1000
  0            60.76 nop/sec
  0            60.76 nop/sec
  0            61.48 nop/sec
  0            61.48 nop/sec
  0            61.44 nop/sec

The scheduling values are as follows:
# sysctl -a | grep sched
kernel.sched_autogroup_enabled = 1
kernel.sched_cfs_bandwidth_slice_us = 5000
kernel.sched_child_runs_first = 0
kernel.sched_deadline_period_max_us = 4194304
kernel.sched_deadline_period_min_us = 100
kernel.sched_energy_aware = 1
kernel.sched_rr_timeslice_ms = 100
kernel.sched_rt_period_us = 1000000
kernel.sched_rt_runtime_us = 950000
kernel.sched_schedstats = 0
kernel.sched_util_clamp_max = 1024
kernel.sched_util_clamp_min = 1024
kernel.sched_util_clamp_min_rt_default = 1024

I played with scheduling setting with to avail. The "perf stat" yield problematic "LLC-load-misses" and "iTLB-load-misses" as shown below:
$ sudo perf stat -d -d -d --timeout 10000 ./perf 2 1000
Creating thread 0
Creating thread 1
Threads=2   memsize=1000
Threads=2   memsize=1000
  1             1.21 nop/sec
  0             0.76 nop/sec
  0             0.72 nop/sec
  1             1.00 nop/sec
  0             2.30 nop/sec
  1             1.30 nop/sec
  1             1.28 nop/sec
  0             2.32 nop/sec
./perf: Terminated

 Performance counter stats for './perf 2 1000':

         19,875.36 msec task-clock                       #    1.985 CPUs utilized             
            24,396      context-switches                 #    1.227 K/sec                     
                 0      cpu-migrations                   #    0.000 /sec                      
               100      page-faults                      #    5.031 /sec                      
    62,051,572,900      cycles                           #    3.122 GHz                         (38.44%)
    12,305,915,977      instructions                     #    0.20  insn per cycle              (46.07%)
     1,770,935,151      branches                         #   89.102 M/sec                       (46.19%)
        20,833,461      branch-misses                    #    1.18% of all branches             (46.14%)
     2,886,437,444      L1-dcache-loads                  #  145.227 M/sec                       (46.08%)
        62,673,587      L1-dcache-load-misses            #    2.17% of all L1-dcache accesses   (46.16%)
        36,380,110      LLC-loads                        #    1.830 M/sec                       (30.73%)
        36,335,895      LLC-load-misses                  #   99.88% of all L1-icache accesses   (30.80%)
   <not supported>      L1-icache-loads                                                       
        14,122,757      L1-icache-load-misses                                                   (30.91%)
     2,893,359,729      dTLB-loads                       #  145.575 M/sec                       (30.77%)
        15,591,131      dTLB-load-misses                 #    0.54% of all dTLB cache accesses  (30.84%)
           154,787      iTLB-loads                       #    7.788 K/sec                       (30.91%)
        30,148,243      iTLB-load-misses                 # 19477.24% of all iTLB cache accesses  (30.72%)
   <not supported>      L1-dcache-prefetches                                                  
   <not supported>      L1-dcache-prefetch-misses                                             

      10.010814854 seconds time elapsed

      11.662038000 seconds user
       8.215249000 seconds sys


I find this quite peculiar. I don't experience such a slowdown when using gcloud or AWS EC2. This seems to undermine the overall purpose of threads.
Does anyone have any insights?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6161322/using-stdlibs-rand-from-multiple-threads and rand is not suitable for getting reasonable profiling results anyway

Change rand() to any simple LFSR and you'll get results much better.

To be more explicit, there is a race condition due to calls of rand and this results in an undefined behaviour. Programs having that should never be profiled, and fixed first (results should be checked prior to any profiling). One typical impact of the undefined behaviour is cache line true sharing which cause cache lines to bounce between cores and threads waiting most of their time waiting for the cache lines to be ready while they should be dirty anyway, serializing this part of the program and slowing it down more than a sequential execution (due to the L3 cache latency).

Oh en btw modulus are notoriously slow. They should be slower than a memory access in the L1 cache and maybe even lower than the L2 cache latency too. It would be better with a shift (for power of 2 values) or values known at compile time. On top of that, modulus are bad for generating random value in a range since this method is statistically biased (the distribution is not uniform).

Thank you, Jérôme Richard. My mistake was using rand/random in a threaded environment ın the test code. Once I switched to a thread-safe alternative, the test code performed as expected.
However, this leads me back to the initial issue: when the thread count exceeds the core count, there's a sudden drop in "total" performance. Something like from 48 threads to 49 threads drops the performance something like one tenth of the 48-thread version. I'll further investigate this issue with a new test code and share my findings with a new question.
Thanks for the other comments as well.

How many cores does your machine have? If it's 48, this will explain.
(Note, instead of cat /proc/cpuinfo use lscpu and instead of cat /proc/version use uname -a)

Ah, yes, you have 24 cores which are able to run 48 threads without need in scheduling, your performance drop is scheduling, you should really need to understand what you measure.

Regarding modulus, the best writeup I'm aware of is https://www.pcg-random.org/posts/bounded-rands.html

int _N; is a reserved identifier and global mutable state, used in an unsafe way to pass data between threads. Sorry for being blunt, but that's not a good way to demonstrate something.
